# sql query to serve ads based on proximity to user

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, distance, proximity

Ok so I am implementing an ads system on my website. I currently store member's latitude / longitude coordinates based on the city they enter upon registering. Each ad will be given the option of also providing geo coordinates and specify a radius in miles (though I would also like an option to specify in KM).

```
Sample tables
--------------users
user_id = 7
name = Charles
lat = xxxxxx.xx
lon = xxxxxx.xx

--------------ads
ad_id = 1121
advertiser_id = 42
ad_type = 728x90
proximity = 50
lat = xxxxxx.xx
lon = xxxxxx.xx
```

I have this piece of code that searches my users database and returns users that are within a specified distance. I figure I can edit it so that it works for my needs. However, instead of showing all users within a distance specified I want to show the ads that are in the distance that the ads themselves specify, since one advertiser may specify a different proximity than another, etc.

Here is the original users proximity query that I use:

```
SELECT users.user_id
     , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$lat."') ) * 
                      cos( radians( users.lat ) ) * 
                      cos( radians( users.lng ) - 
                           radians('".$lng."') ) + 
                      sin( radians('".$lat."') ) * 
                      sin( radians( users.lat ) ) 
                    ) ) AS distance 
  FROM users 
 WHERE account_type = '1' 
   AND `active` = '1' 
HAVING distance <= '".$dist."'"
```

So I think if I maybe first create a query to get the ads that match the zone and have proximity requirements and then select their latitude / longitude and select the current users geo coordinates, and then ...... I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Then I will perform several calculations based on the different proximity settings each ad that matches zone. If one ad wants to show people within 100miles then the calculation will be different than the guy who wants his ad displayed only to those within 20miles. There's probably a simpler way of doing this. Would this be something that a query builder app could help create?

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT ads.ad_id
     , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$user_lat."') ) * 
                      cos( radians( ads.lat ) ) * 
                      cos( radians( ads.lng ) - 
                           radians('".$user_lng."') ) + 
                      sin( radians('".$user_lat."') ) * 
                      sin( radians( ads.lat ) ) 
                    )) AS distance 
  FROM ads 
 WHERE ad_type = '728x90' 
   AND `active` = '1' 
HAVING distance <= ads.proximity"
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, Charles lives in a city, so I would expect to see a separate table for cities, and their respective coordinates (and possibly approximate radii)

Comment: expensive SQL to run a large number of internet users are running adblockers  annyway..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, but this solution serves all of my ad serving needs including banners, blocks, html ads, iframes, and video ads. I don't think the adblockers will block all of them such video ads, though I could be mistaken. Thanks for everyone's input. Got it working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The final query solution I came up with was this:

```
SELECT ads.ad_id
     , proximity AS P, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$usr_lat."') ) * 
                                      cos( radians( ads.lat ) ) * 
                                      cos( radians( ads.lon ) - 
                                           radians('".$usr_lon."') ) + 
                                      sin( radians('".$usr_lat."') ) * 
                                      sin( radians( ads.lat ) ) 
                                    ) ) AS distance 
FROM ads 
WHERE ads.type = '728x90' 
AND ads.active = '1' 
HAVING distance <= P 
OR P='0' 
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

I added the OR P='0' to serve ads that have not specified a proximity.

Answer (score 0):

You could as well further limit the amount of data you have to calculate before you do all the maths.

you can limit the range of data you have to calculate distances for when you limit the latitude/longitude values to the ones nearby. (formulas coming [from these slides (page 12ff)](http://de.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) This works when you calculate by miles... otherwise you have to adjust the "69" with the right value for kilometers.

```
1° of latitude ~= 69 miles 
1° of longitude ~= cos(latitude)*69
```

When you want to calculate the longitude and latitude for the smaller rectangle, you can use (with your variables above):

```
$lon1 = $lon - $dist / abs(cos(deg2rad($lat))*69);
$lon2 = $lon + $dist / abs(cos(deg2rad($lat))*69);
$lat1 = $lat - ($dist / 69);
$lat2 = $lat + ($dist / 69);
```

and then you modify your query like so:

```
SELECT ads.ad_id
     , proximity AS P, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$usr_lat."') ) * 
                                      cos( radians( ads.lat ) ) * 
                                      cos( radians( ads.lon ) - 
                                           radians('".$usr_lon."') ) + 
                                      sin( radians('".$usr_lat."') ) * 
                                      sin( radians( ads.lat ) ) 
                                    ) ) AS distance 
FROM ads 
WHERE ads.type = '728x90' 
AND ads.active = '1' 
AND ads.lon BETWEEN $lon1 AND $lon2 
AND ads.lat BETWEEN $lat1 AND $lat2
HAVING distance <= P 
OR P='0' 
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

This should improve the overall speed drastically since you only use a subset of all the coordinates.

And one other remark: If you have your lat/lon/distance as numeric fields, you should not use '' around the values, since this triggers implicit conversion, which might take some time as well...